# How to pass cairo_surface_t as a parameter in g_signal_connect?

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome, cairo

I intend to create a generic callback function for all `configure-event` and `g_signal_connect`. It looks like this:

```cpp
int
generic_configure_event(
    GtkWidget *widget,
    GdkEventConfigure *event,
    void *gData)
{
    cairo_surface_t *surface = static_cast<cairo_surface_t *>(gData);
    ...
    if (*surface)
        cairo_surface_destroy(*surface);

    *surface  = gdk_window_create_similar_surface(
        gtk_widget_get_window(widget), CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR,
        save_w, save_h);

    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(*surface);

    return TRUE;
}

int
main(){
    g_signal_connect(widget1,"configure-event",G_CALLBACK(generic_configure_event),&surface1);
    g_signal_connect(widget2,"configure-event",G_CALLBACK(generic_configure_event),&surface2);
    g_signal_connect(widget3,"configure-event",G_CALLBACK(generic_configure_event),&surface3);
    ...
}
```

Adding more to the complication is that other than passing the `cairo_surface_t` as an argument, we also got to updated that specific surface in the `generic_configure_event`. Using the above gets me a segfault, what woud be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: What type is surface? You are passing &surface to the events and then cast this pointer to cairo_surface_t*. That would mean that surface has type cairo_surface_t, but that is impossible, because it is an opaque struct that you cannot create instances of yourself....?!?

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want some guidance on the segfault. We can't guess what you're really doing.